# Sort data frames by numerical value to be able to join them with rbind

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, rbind

I have to join 60 dataframes named: coord1, coord2, coord3, ... , coord60, in a numerical order, that is: I need to create a new_df with coord1 on the top and coord60 on the bottom.

To do this I do the following:

```
new_df <- do.call("rbind",mget(ls(pattern(pattern = "^coord"))))
```

the problem is that it joins the data frames but instead of doing it by the logical order of the numbers from 1 to 60 it does it in the following order:

```
coord1, coord10, coord11, coord12..., coord19, coord2,coord20,....
```

how could I solve this and have it order them coord1, coord2, coord3,.... coord60?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
coord1 <- coord2 <- coord11 <- mtcars[1:2,1:3]
alldat <- mget(ls(pattern="^coord"))
alldat
# $coord1
#               mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
# $coord11
#               mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
# $coord2
#               mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
alldat <- alldat[ order(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", names(alldat)))) ]
alldat
# $coord1
#               mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
# $coord2
#               mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
# $coord11
#               mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
do.call(rbind, alldat)
#                       mpg cyl disp
# coord1.Mazda RX4       21   6  160
# coord1.Mazda RX4 Wag   21   6  160
# coord2.Mazda RX4       21   6  160
# coord2.Mazda RX4 Wag   21   6  160
# coord11.Mazda RX4      21   6  160
# coord11.Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160
```